# Asp.net CustomValidator client validation not firing when response comes from jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to validate an email textbox on blur using jQuery AJAX with an ASP.net webforms CustomValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<asp:CustomValidator ID="EmailRegisteredValidatation" ControlToValidate="Email" runat="server"
                        ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"  ClientValidationFunction="CheckEmailRegistration"
                        ErrorMessage="Email Already Registered"></asp:CustomValidator>


 function CheckEmailRegistration(sender, args)
    {
        $.post("/api/CheckEmailRegistration/", { Email: $("#Email").val() })
        .done(function (data) {
          args.IsValid = data;
        });
    }
```

That script isn't working. It doesn't change the validation status. I know for sure the returned data is either true or false. But I'm guessing the delay of the AJAX result is causing a problem.

This works ok:

```
  function CheckEmailRegistration(sender, args)
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
```

This also doesn't work:

```
function CheckEmailRegistration(sender, args)
    {
    $.post("/api/CheckEmailRegistration/", { Email: $("#Email").val() })
    .done(function (data) {
      args.IsValid = false;  //even hardcoded doesn't work
    });
    }
```

Outside of the scope also doesn't work:

```
  function CheckEmailRegistration(sender, args)
    {
        var _value;
        $.post("/api/CheckEmailRegistration/", { Email: $("#Email").val() })
        .done(function (data) {
            _value = data;
            }
        });

        args.IsValid = _value;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Have you verified that the post is actually being made by using the network tab in chrome inspector or the network tab in internet explorer developer tools? If so are you actually getting a response? My guess is the request is not being made properly, maybe the url is not valid?

Comment: Oh this just dawned on me too, since .done is a callback function the scope of args.IsValid may be wrong, meaning you may not have access to args.IsValid. So you may need to set a local variable at the top of the function, set data to that in the callback .done, then set args.IsValid to the local variable from the scope of the function, not withing .done.

Comment: thanks mike, I'm 100% sure the the post and results are correct. I have checked it with firebug. 
About your second comment, I had the same assumption. I tried that too and also didn't work, I'm guessing even doing it that way with arags.IsValid at the end, it gets fired before .done with whatever default value had been set. thank you

Comment: Can you please try to use this method on your text box blur event: ValidatorValidate(val). val is client side validator object. Keep the validator disabled by default and on-blur first enable it and then fire it using the method give above. Refer to this link to enable/disable validators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Comment: Maybe try using .success instead of .done so `$.post("/api/CheckEmailRegistration", { Email: $("#Email").val() }).success(function(data) { alert(typeof(args)); });` Also do you have an extra } at the end of .done, that may be your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but still hasn't work